# Can the max of a polynomial be near a zero?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

The setup of this question is very similar to a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048517/mass-of-polynomial-away-from-zeros) I asked.

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with complex zeros $\{z_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset\mathbb{C}$.  Let $Z\subset \mathbb{C}$ be the set near the zeros,
$$
Z = \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_{(100n)^{-1}}(z_i),
$$
where $D_r(x)\subset \mathbb{C}$ is the disk of radius $r$ centered at $x$.  Let $\gamma$ be the line segment $[-1,1]$ on the real axis in the complex plane.

I am interested in whether the inequality
$$
\sup_{\gamma\cap Z} |p(x)| \leq  \sup_{x\in \gamma\setminus Z} |p(x)| 
$$
holds.  In other words, is it possible that the maximum value of $p$ on the line segment $\gamma$ takes place in $Z$?

It seems that the maximum principle might be useful here, but I am only interested in what happens to the polynomial on a line segment (which does not contain any disks in the complex plane).  I am not sure how to proceed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no!  Consider the Chebyshev polynomial $T_n(x)$ with roots
$$
x_k = \cos\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n}\pi\right),
$$
and which satisfies $|T_n(x)| \leq T_n(1)$.  The $n$-th root is a distance $\Theta(n^{-2})$ away from the maximum value.